# call JavaScript function within Google Maps Listener

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Ok, simple question but is it possible to call an external javascript function within a google maps listener?

```
GEvent.addListener(map,"click", function(overlay, latlng) {
 testfunction(latlng);
});
```

testfunction doesn't run, so is there a particular way i need to go about this? I'm new to google maps and javascript.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try your listener handler function with one parameter at first:  a [GLatLng](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GLatLng) object that corresponds to the latitude/longitude where the user clicked on the map.

Give this a try initially:

```
GEvent.addListener(map, "click", function(latlng) {
    testfunction(latlng);
});
```

If that doesn't work, ensure that your `testfunction` is handling the GLatLng type properly (using the object's properties correctly, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible. Otherwise it would be useless. Try to include your funnction definition within the same script tag and check if it works.

Comment: all functions are in same script tag

Comment: I know the listener is working, because if i do an alert it pops up fine, but calling a function I have defined it doesn't do anything, even if that functions only job is to do an alert.